# Will someone create a pokemon-second-generation and pokemon-third-generation tag, please?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, pokemon

It would seem that all of the other generations are represented except for these ones. I can't yet add tags.

Will you please add them for us?

Comment: Can you add the questions that need to be tagged with these?  You haven't asked any.  Tags have no need to exist without questions (and will actually be deleted after a time without any.)

Comment: [Second Generation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/32972/13423) &  [Third](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1488/13423)  And I should be able to find/make more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags can't exist without questions to apply them to.

If you know of some existing questions that need this tag applied, you can just retag them (if you have 500 rep) or flag them (if you don't). You can also retag a question by submitting an edit, but you'll have to make a more substantial change as well for the system to allow it. (But you'll also *earn* a couple points!)